# Q - iOS - Search and use specific part of parsed JSON array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

This is my first time using JSON. In my app I am fetching some data from "Open Weather API". I get back some array, with way to many entries, and I need to search ones that are on specific day and return **temp.day** and **weather.icon** from them. So far I managed to fetch data propely. As far I know i should use some FOR loop with IF inside it, but I am pulling my hairs out how to do it in Objective C.

There is my fetch method:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* weatherList = [json objectForKey:@"list"];
    NSLog(@"everything %@", weatherList ); //3
    }
```

And part array from NSLog:

```
{
        clouds = 92;
        deg = 265;
        dt = 1456221600;
        humidity = 100;
        pressure = "1007.96";
        rain = "0.24";
        speed = "5.12";
        temp =         {
            day = "4.11";
            eve = "4.62";
            max = "4.87";
            min = "2.78";
            morn = "4.11";
            night = "2.78";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light rain";
                icon = 10d;
                id = 500;
                main = Rain;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        clouds = 88;
        deg = 268;
        dt = 1456308000;
        humidity = 98;
        pressure = "1012.04";
        rain = "1.31";
        speed = "6.35";
        temp =         {
            day = "3.57";
            eve = "3.74";
            max = "3.74";
            min = "2.38";
            morn = "2.53";
            night = "2.38";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light rain";
                icon = 10d;
                id = 500;
                main = Rain;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        clouds = 20;
        deg = 243;
        dt = 1456394400;
        humidity = 100;
        pressure = "1015.42";
        snow = "0.25";
        speed = "5.08";
        temp =         {
            day = "2.95";
            eve = "4.09";
            max = "4.54";
            min = "-0.65";
            morn = "1.74";
            night = "-0.65";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light snow";
                icon = 13d;
                id = 600;
                main = Snow;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        clouds = 80;
        deg = 273;
        dt = 1456480800;
        humidity = 100;
        pressure = "1016.63";
        snow = "0.04";
        speed = "2.79";
        temp =         {
            day = "0.2";
            eve = "2.79";
            max = "2.79";
            min = "-3.33";
            morn = "-2.7";
            night = "-2.42";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light snow";
                icon = 13d;
                id = 600;
                main = Snow;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        clouds = 87;
        deg = 132;
        dt = 1456567200;
        humidity = 0;
        pressure = "1007.07";
        rain = "0.22";
        snow = "0.03";
        speed = 5;
        temp =         {
            day = "3.96";
            eve = "1.48";
            max = "3.96";
            min = "-3.12";
            morn = "-3.12";
            night = "-1.59";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "clear sky";
                icon = 01d;
                id = 800;
                main = Clear;
            }
        );
    }
```

What are good practices? Do I fetch proper enough big part of JSON?

Should I use dome NSDictionary too? Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: You could use a `NSPredicate` to filter only the interesting data.

Comment: I don't exactly see how could I use this. Seems strange - how I can be sure that no object has been stripped or swapped?

Comment: which is todays date dictionary

Comment: According to the API docs - 
list.dt is the time of data forecasted. But I don't know if it is in seconds. This is the forecast for 16 days.

Comment: I think you are fetching 5 days data as I saw on website

Comment: I am sure that I am fetching 16 days. There was no use to paste whole array with 16 days, so I pasted just a part of it.

Comment: how you filter todays data

Comment: I don't. I just want to compare if it's same date as some point of time from now. I need forecast for this specific day.

Answer (score 1):

1) As per documentation given the time is in GMT format so you need to convert the time in `IST` to compare
here is code to convert the time . I dont know your time zone I converted it in `Indian Standard Time`

```
     for ( NSDictionary *obj in weatherList) {

          NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
          inDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
          inDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone     timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
          NSDate *inDate = [inDateFormatter dateFromString:[obj objectForKey:@"dt"]];

    if ([self isItToday:inDate]) {

         NSDictionary * tempDict = [obj objectForKey:@"temp"];
         NSDictionary * weatherDict = [[obj objectForKey:@"weather"]objectForKey:0];

         NSString * dayTemp = [tempDict objectForKey:@"day"];//only storing for time being you can use where you needed
         NSString * icon = [weatherDict objectForKey:@"icon"];//only storing for time being you can use where you needed
     }
  }
```

2) Now you need to compare it with todays date

```
+ (BOOL)isItToday:(NSDate *)date {

        if (date != nil) {
            NSString *givenDateString = [self stringFromDate:date inDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSString *toDayString = [self stringFromDate:[NSDate date] inDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

            NSDate *givenDate = [self dateFromString:givenDateString inDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSDate *toDay = [self dateFromString:toDayString inDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

            if ([givenDate isEqualToDate:toDay]) {
                return YES;
            } else {
                return NO;
            }
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
}




+ (NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date inDateFormat:(NSString *)inDateformat
{

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:kLocaleIdentifierEN_US_POSIX];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:inDateformat];//@"dd/MM/yyyy"
        return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
  }

+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)stringDate inDateFormat:(NSString *)inDateformat
{

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:kLocaleIdentifierEN_US_POSIX];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:inDateformat];//@"dd/MM/yyyy"
        return [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

}
```

also add this line

```
#define kLocaleIdentifierEN_US_POSIX [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]
```

Comment: I get few errors - "No known class method for selector 'stringFromDate:inDate".
I declared bool function in .h file

Comment: please add two more funtions

Comment: :< - another error -Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7875fc40'

Comment: I have not compiled this code. but the core logic is correct, you need make some workaround

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer I was looking for. - but logic is very well built! My problem is - how to get to selected body in JSON.

Comment: As you said you need only two parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use following code,

```
  double comparingdt = 1456308000;

__block NSString *tempday, *weathericon;

[weatherList enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSDictionary  *weather, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    *stop = ([weather[@"dt"] doubleValue] == comparingdt);

    if (*stop)
    {
        tempday = weather[@"temp"][@"day"];
        weathericon = [weather[@"weather"] firstObject][@"icon"];
    }

}];
```